# Making report from DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, crystal-reports, report

I have my main form where I have my DataTable filled with all data. Now I want to click my button and go to another form and pass all values to that form. 
It's easy, but I want make report with Crystal Reports.

So on another form I have to have report which will be filled with data from DataTable.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: This question is very broad. There are quite a few ways to accomplish this depending on your goal and your environment. You could save the data to a database or flat file on the file system, you could make a class to hold the data and pass that to the form, etc.

Comment: I read it from database and using it on one form in table... I have already made a class for that data in table using it perfectly on other forms but now need to use that data for report, but I don't know way how to pass that data table to report.